# Swift Expression<Array>("column", <#[Binding?]#>) What is this Binding?

Tags: arrays, swift, binding, expression

I'm trying to understand swift by building, now I run into a problem but don't understand wat this means. I was suggested by Xcode to add 'Binding' to the expression when I change the type from String to Array. Now I don't have a clue what to do next. Can anyone help me in the right direction. Did search for bindings but got so many different explanations but nothing I could link to Expression.

KR

Comment: Aren't you editing a code that uses some kind of a reactive library?

Comment: Well I’m using SQLite.swift for this, I don’t know if that’s a reactive library?